# Cannot Find Method 'SetState' within widget

Tags: drop-down-menu, flutter, dropdown, setstate

I have a widget that is called in my main scaffolding file later. This widget contains a dropdown menu but, I cannot change the state when selecting another value. The field does not update and I get the error message 'error: Method not found: 'setState'.
                    setState(() {'
                    ^^^^^^^^

I have updated the setState method and removed code from it but, it still says the method not found.

```
child: DropdownButton(
                  hint: Text('Medical'),
                  value: _selectedCustomerType,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedCustomerType = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items: _customerType.map((cusType) {
                    print(cusType);

                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(cusType),
                      value: cusType,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
```

I need to be able to update the value and display it when the new value is chosen.

Comment: add your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use setState outside of a [StatefulWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) so you should wrap your DropdownButton in a StatefulWidget, for example:

```
class StatefulDropdownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> _customerType;

  StatefulDropdownButton(this._customerType);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => DropdownButtonState();
}

class DropdownButtonState extends State<StatefulDropdownButton> {
  String _selectedCustomerType;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      hint: Text('Medical'),
      value: _selectedCustomerType,
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedCustomerType = newValue;
        });
      },
      items: widget._customerType.map((cusType) {
        print(cusType);

        return DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(cusType),
          value: cusType,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. I tried to use the set state outside of the Stateful widget.

Answer (score 1):

SetState is not accessible inside the main method, and neither inside function, to make it accessible , you need to create a Stateful class and exactly in the State class , because actually your widget is a statefull class : it changes its state everytime the user make an event..

Comment: I can't capture the class. This is a widget that gets called by the main widget.

Comment: SetState is not accessible inside the main method, and neither inside function, to make it accessible , you need to create a Stateful class and exactly in the State class , because actually your widget is a statefull class : it changes its state everytime the user make an event..